# When and why should I create tables for attributes that only accept values from a pre determined list?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I tried searching for definite answers for this, but couldn't.

Every time I create a new database, I create auxiliary tables for specific attributes like Marital Status and Gender. This way on the Customer table, I'll simply place an ID on the Marital Status column.
    1 - Single
    2 - Divorced
    3 - Married

Etc...

I have always done this, it is how I learned it, I know it is good practice, etc. But are there better "arguments" or hard facts as to why do this?

Basically, someone I work with wants to build a new database and to make Customer_Type a text field, without linking it to another table, and I want to explain why this is bad practice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad practice because you can't limit text columns to only holding valid values. You could put a gender of 'potato' for example. Another reason is that text columns will take up a lot more space than int columns that link to the auxiliary table. This means the table will take less space on disk and the rows will be more cacheable. Also, indexing an integer column is can be faster than indexing a text column, depending on the length of the text values.

In MySQL you can, however, create Enumeration columns that only have the valid values.

Comment: But that can be prevented with the front end. Or if you are dealing with values imported from somewhere else, it wont really be a problem.

Comment: You can't be 100% certain all data will come through the front-end. Admins often have make edits in the database directly. If it can happen, it will happen. Ensuring your data can't be wrong is a huge part of database design.

Comment: We are creating a data warehouse using data from another database. So we can be 100% sure the data will be good.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly depicted by @Swoogan, declaring `gender`, `status` and similar type of fields as *varchar* is a bad practice as data sanity will be hampered.

Alternatively we can put them [enum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html). Enum datatypes are shown in database as texts but are stored more efficiently and only allow values from specific enumerable values mentioned at the time of creation of table e.g. `('male', 'female', 'others')` in case of `gender`.

```
gender enum('male', 'female', 'others')
```

You can also create a separate table for all possible genders and specify the field `gender_id` as a foreign key as you have mentioned in your question. This is an ideal scenario but the former is a denormalised solution of the problem or else you need to join every-time you need to find the value of the gender.